# QMediaPlayer crashes when pausing playback

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I have a longer wav-file, where I wanted to play smaller parts. 
I stored startTime and endTime as qint64 and already loaded the audiofile:

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), this, SLOT(slotTick(qint64)));

player->setNotifyInterval(10);
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(mediasource));
...
player->setPosition(startTime);
player->play();
```

I observe the position with the positionChanged Signal andd use the following slot, to stop the playback once the end of the desired part is reached:

```
void PlayerWidget::slotTick(qint64 time){
if(endTime >= 0 && time >= endTime){
    if(player->state() == QMediaPlayer::PlayingState){
        player->stop();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the program crashes shortly after the player stops. WHat could be the reason

Comment: Are there any error messages?  Do you have any other clues?

Comment: I have the same problem (using PyQt5.7). I get an access violation when pausing using a slotTick that is connected to positionChanged. It crashes if I pause or stop. Very similar code worked fine with Phonon.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue, and while I don't really know the underlying reason, I managed to somehow intuit a solution that actually works.

Instead of calling `player->stop()` directly, trigger it with a singleShot `QTimer`. Python code equivalent: `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, player.stop)`.

Comment: It probably has to do with Qt not being reentrant in this case. I ran into something like this recently, trying to call `QMediaPlayer::pause()` from an overloaded `QAbstractVideoSurface::present()` callback. Using `QTimer::singleShot(0, &mediaPlayer, &QMediaPlayer::pause)` solved my problem! Thank you for suggesting it!